# Iterate a python dictionary loaded from yaml

Tags: python, yaml

Yaml file:

```
tests:
  test1:
    one:
      description:
        - test one
      method:
        - runTestOne
    two:
      description:
        - test two
      method:
        - runTestTwo
    three:
      description:
        - test three
      method:
        - runTestThree
  test2:
    one:
      description:
        - test one
      method:
        - runTestOne
  test3:
    one:
      description:
        - teste one
      method:
        - runTestOne
```

yaml.py

```
import os
import pprint

import ruamel.yaml
from ruamel.yaml.scanner import ScannerError

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()

if os.path.exists('test.yaml'):
    with open('test.yaml', 'r', encoding='utf8') as file:
        try:
            dictionary = yaml.load(file)
        except ScannerError as error:
            print('Yaml file structure is invalid')
else:
    print('Yaml file not exists')

pprint.pprint(dictionary['tests'])
```

dictionary print:

```
{'test1': {'one': {'description': ['test one'],
                   'method': ['runTestOne']},
           'three': {'description': ['test three'],
                     'method': ['runTestThree']},
           'two': {'description': ['test two'],
                   'method': ['runTestTwo']}},
 'test2': {'one': {'description': ['test one'],
                   'method': ['runTestOne']}},
 'test3': {'one': {'description': ['teste one'],
                   'method': ['runTestOne']}}}
```

I need iterate the dictionary, readed from a yaml file, to obtain the nodes names according with this example:

```
test1.one
test1.two
test1.three
test2.one
test3.one
```

I´m using Python 3.8.5

I've tried it in several ways, but I´m a Python newbie, and I couldn't come up with an implementation to resolve this.

I will be grateful for any help.

Regard´s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need a nested iteration on your `dict`

**Demo:**

```
dictionary = {'test1': {'one': {'description': ['test one'],
                   'method': ['runTestOne']},
           'three': {'description': ['test three'],
                     'method': ['runTestThree']},
           'two': {'description': ['test two'],
                   'method': ['runTestTwo']}},
 'test2': {'one': {'description': ['test one'],
                   'method': ['runTestOne']}},
 'test3': {'one': {'description': ['teste one'],
                   'method': ['runTestOne']}}}

for k,v in dictionary.items():
    for m, n in v.items():
        node = f"{k}.{m}"
        print(node)
```

**Output:**

```
test1.one
test1.three
test1.two
test2.one
test3.one
```